# Sql batch processing in nodejs, should revoke changes if any one query fails to execute

Tags: sql, node.js

In nodejs i want to insert data 3 different tables, if any one query fails to execute i want all the changes done by the other queries to revoke the changes in the table.

Answer (score 0):

See this part of `mysql` package documentation: https://github.com/mysqljs/mysql#transactions

Only once you execute all 3 queries you can call `connection.commit()` to apply changes or `connection.rollback()` to revert changes as shown on the example on the link.

Comment: Thanks Luka. But when i tried to execute the above code i can't do the rollback and commit. It is telling that connection.rollback() and conncetion.commit() is not a function.

Comment: It's hard to say without seeing any code. Could you please provide at least the relevant parts of the code and copy the error message you're getting?